# How can I check the existence of `expect_out(buffer)` (and related)?

Tags: undefined, expect

Debugging a script of mine, I wanted to print `expect_out(buffer)` (and related, like `expect_out(0, string)`, but occasionally I get this error:

```text
can't read "expect_out(buffer)": no such variable
```

So I wonder:
Is it possible to check the existence of `expect_out(buffer)` to avoid that error?

I tried a test like `if { $expect_out(0,start) > 0 }`, but that failed with a corresponding error message (`can't read "expect_out(0,start)": no such variable`).

Comment: you can use Tcl's [info exists *varName*](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm) command.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment of https://stackoverflow.com/users/13534458/sexpect-expect-for-shells saying

> you can use Tcl's info exists varName command.

I replaced

```tcl
if { $expect_out(0,start) > 0 }
```

with

```tcl
if { [info exists expect_out(0,start)] }
```

and it seems to do the job.